# SO jobs - contacted by a recruiter

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, spam

I've just been contacted by a recruiter (according to Linkedin) on the jobs section. He refers to a specific position, vaguely specifies "fullstack .net", and follows with a bunch of very recruiter-y sounding usual stuff.

Am I supposed to get these?

Comment: Has the recruiter contacted you via SO Jobs or via Linkedin? (Just trying to check this has anything at all to do with SO)

Comment: SO jobs, it sounded the usual recruiter tone so I checked on Linkedin

Comment: Have you said in your profile that you're either actively seeking work or "not actively looking but open to suggestions"?

Comment: Companies sometimes employ *internal* recruiters. These do not work on commission, they are actively looking to fill positions *at their own company*. Is this recruiter type you found such a person, or are you sure they work for a recruitment agency?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned by Jon, your [job match preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) indicate that you are actively looking. That, coupled with your Developer Story, means that you are indexed in our Candidate Search database and are therefore likely to be contacted by  employers regarding open positions.

If you no longer want to receive those messages you can set your status to 'Not Looking' and you'll no longer be surfaced in Candidate Search. You can also block the employer by clicking 'Block Employer' in the messaging UI.

That said, the message you received was really not inline with our house rules and didn't contain anything about what job they were hiring for. We're looking into this now and will reach out to the employer to get them to send messages that actually have some use to the recipient in future.

Apologies for the inconvenience and thanks for the report.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm indeed looking, however I do not want to deal with recruiters and this is clearly one, not someone working in the company, just a usual recruiter trying to match companies with employees just like monster, indeed, or any other platform.